# updating to python 3 on a mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I'm following the instructions here: http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/ for updating from python 2 to 3 on a mac

and have downloaded Python 3.4.1 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer on https://www.python.org/download/

The problems is, after I run the installer Python.mpkg file, it would put "3.4" in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

however,

```
>>cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
>>ls
2.3 2.5 2.6 2.7 Current
```

no 3.4 to be found. What is going on here and can someone suggest the most straightforward way to start using python 3 on a mac?

Comment: Use `homebrew` to install your Python versions. Much, much easier.

Comment: That tutorial sounds like an awful thing to follow. Advising people to `sudo rm` stuff in /System/Library is extremely irresponsible.

Comment: Try the newer 3.4.2c1 (release candidate) installer or wait a few days for the final 3.4.2 installer.  If that does not work, please post "Problem with Mac OSX 3.4.2 installer" on python-list and someone, maybe the installer maintainer, should answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to install Python 3.4 from Anaconda distribution: http://continuum.io/downloads#py34
On my Mac installer did entire job for me.